# Special characters doesn't show up properly

Tags: 18.04, text, encoding

Every time when I download a subtitle with special characters like ă,ș and ț (Romanian special characters) my system convert the characters in ã,º and þ.
If I try to replace the characters in gedit I receive this error:

```
Could not save the file using the “Western (ISO-8859-15)” character encoding.
The document contains one or more characters that cannot be encoded using the specified character encoding.
Select a different character encoding from the menu and try again.
Character Encoding Current Locate UTF-8
```

I don't want to convert every file I'll download, I want to read my text files properly by default.
I solved this problem a few years ago but after a fresh install, I can't remember what I did. I have Ubuntu 18.04.1

Answer (score 0):

I have no universal solution for that, but it is in particular for subtitles that I always have the light weight text editor `leafpad` installed. `leafpad` is extremely good to recognize the code page of a text file, and usually opens it correctly. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> then allows to "save as": in the dialog, leave the file name, but change the encoding to UTF-8.

There is a terminal command `iconv` that allows to change character codes as well. However, you need to know the current character code yourself before doing the conversion. You can obtain that with the command `file -b --mime-encoding <yourfile>`.